# Javascript: How to get multiple matches in RegEx .exec results

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, v8

When I run

```
/(a)/g.exec('a a a ').length
```

I get

```
2
```

but I thought it should return

```
3
```

because there are 3 `a`s in the string, not 2!

Why is that?

I want to be able to search for all occurances of a string in RegEx and iterate over them.

FWIW: I'm using node.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Regexp loop all matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835418/javascript-regexp-loop-all-matches)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`exec()` is returning only the set of captures for the first match, not the set of matches as you expect.  So what you're really seeing is `$0` (the entire match, "a") and `$1` (the first capture)--i.e. an array of length 2.  `exec()` meanwhile is designed so that you can call it *again* to get the captures for the *next* match.  From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

> If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the exec method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string. When you do so, the search starts at the substring of str specified by the regular expression's lastIndex property (test will also advance the lastIndex property).

Comment: Btw, the entire match is `$&` in js.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't even know there were such ``$`` variables in JS.  I was just speaking in Perl.  :)  Good to know, though.

Comment: @Qtax, are you talking about the replace method, or some other context?

Comment: @rambo, in the replacement string only.

Answer (score 35):

You could use `match` instead:

```
'a a a'.match(/(a)/g).length  // outputs: 3
```

Comment: Indeed, `match` is the ideal tool for this case, provided that the OP doesn't need subgroups from within each match.

Comment: Provided there is always at least one match. Otherwise `match` returns `null` instead of an empty array.

Answer (score 26):

**while loop** can help you

```
x = 'a a a a';
y = new RegExp(/a/g);
while(null != (z=y.exec(x))) {
   console.log(z);     // output: object
   console.log(z[0]);  // ouput: "a"
}
```

If you add counter then you get length of it.

```
x = 'a a a a';
counter = 0;
y = new RegExp(/a/g);
while(null != (z=y.exec(x))) {
   console.log(z);     // output: object
   console.log(z[0]);  // output: "a"
   counter++;
}
console.log(counter);  // output: 4
```

This is quite safe, even if it doesn't find any matching then it just exits and counter will be 0

Main intention is to tell how RegExp can be used to loop and get all values from string of same matched RegExp

Comment: +1 I think this is best solution. `.exec` returns some extra properties that are not returned by `.match`, and it is meant to be called iteratively to return each incremental match. FYI you can remove `null !=` from the while loop as a null value will be falsy and exit the loop anyway.  Also, Happy Bounty Bingo!

Comment: @KyleMit, Thank you for the Bounty! 
Yes we can remove `null !=`. But I feel it will help for few new comers to understand code flow.

Comment: Very efficient solution, this one. I did however try this one out using RegExp without the `'g'` flag (global). Not using that will produce an infinite loop.

Comment: @andiOak -- 
Yes, removing `'g'` flag will go into infinite loop because every time the search pointer will re-point to starting point 0.

Comment: `y = /a/g` will suffice since it's already a regex. Calling `new RegExp()` is redundant.

Answer (score 8):

You are only matching the first a.  The reason the length is two is that it is finding the first match and the parenthesized group part of the first match.  In your case they are the same.

Consider this example.

```
var a = /b(a)/g.exec('ba ba ba ');
alert(a);
```

It outputs `ba, a`.  The array length is still 2, but it is more obvious what is going on.  "ba" is the full match.  `a` is the parenthesized first grouping match.

The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) supports this - that only the first match and contained groups are returned.  To find all matches, you'd use match() as stated by mVChr.

Answer (score 4):

***Code:***

```
alert('a a a'.match(/(a)/g).length);
```

***Output:***

```
3
```

Answer (score 2):

`regexp.exec(str)` returns the first match or the entire match and the first capture (when `re = /(a)/g;` ) as mentionned in other answers

```js
const str = 'a a a a a a a a a a a a a';
const re = /a/g;

const result = re.exec(str);
console.log(result);
```

But it also **remembers** the position after it in `regexp.lastIndex` property.

The next call starts to search from `regexp.lastIndex` and returns the next match.

If there are no more matches then `regexp.exec` returns null and `regexp.lastIndex` is set to 0.

```js
const str = 'a a a';
const re = /a/g;

const a = re.exec(str);
console.log('match : ', a, ' found at : ', re.lastIndex);

const b = re.exec(str);
console.log('match : ', b, ' found at : ', re.lastIndex);

const c = re.exec(str);
console.log('match : ', c, ' found at : ', re.lastIndex);

const d = re.exec(str);
console.log('match : ', d, ' found at : ', re.lastIndex);

const e = re.exec(str);
console.log('match : ', e, ' found at : ', re.lastIndex);
```

That's why you can use a while loop that will stop when the match is `null`

```js
const str = 'a a a';
const re = /a/g;

while(match = re.exec(str)){
  console.log(match, ' found at : ', match.index); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several answers already but unnecessarily complicated. The identity check on the result is excessive because it is always either an array or `null`.

```js
let text = `How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?`;
let re = /wood/g;
let lastMatch;

while (lastMatch = re.exec(text)) {
  console.log(lastMatch);
  console.log(re.lastIndex);

  // Avoid infinite loop
  if(!re.global) break;
}
```

You can move the infinite loop guard into the conditional expression.

```js
while (re.global && (lastMatch = re.exec(text))) {
 console.log(lastMatch);
 console.log(re.lastIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your example, `.match()` is your best option.  However, if you do need subgroups, you can make a generator function.

```js
function* execAll(str, regex) {
  if (!regex.global) {
    console.error('RegExp must have the global flag to retrieve multiple results.');
  }

  let match;
  while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
    yield match;
  }
}

const matches = execAll('a abbbbb no match ab', /\b(a)(b+)?\b/g);
for (const match of matches) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(match));
  let otherProps = {};
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(match)) {
    if (isNaN(Number(key))) {
      otherProps[key] = value;
    }
  }
  
  console.log(otherProps);
}
```

While most JS programmers consider polluting a prototype to be bad practice, you could also add this to `RegExp.prototype`.

```js
if (RegExp.prototype.hasOwnProperty('execAll')) {
  console.error('RegExp prototype already includes a value for execAll.  Not overwriting it.');
} else {
  RegExp.prototype.execAll = 
    RegExp.prototype = function* execAll(str) {
      if (!this.global) {
        console.error('RegExp must have the global flag to retrieve multiple results.');
      }

      let match;
      while (match = this.exec(str)) {
        yield match;
      }
    };
}

const matches = /\b(a)(b+)?\b/g.execAll('a abbbbb no match ab');
console.log(Array.from(matches));
```

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulated into a utility function:

```
const regexExecAll = (str: string, regex: RegExp) => {
  let lastMatch: RegExpExecArray | null;
  const matches: RegExpExecArray[] = [];

  while ((lastMatch = regex.exec(str))) {
    matches.push(lastMatch);

    if (!regex.global) break;
  }

  return matches;
};
```

**Usage:**

```
const matches = regexExecAll("a a a", /(a)/g);

console.log(matches);
```

**Output:**

```
[
  [ 'a', 'a', index: 0, input: 'a a a', groups: undefined ],
  [ 'a', 'a', index: 2, input: 'a a a', groups: undefined ],
  [ 'a', 'a', index: 4, input: 'a a a', groups: undefined ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate throw a regex without using `while` you can use `replace`.

**Example:**

```js
const foo = 'a a a';
foo.replace(/(a)/g, (...regex) => {
  // Do something forEach regex found
  console.log(regex);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Spread `<string>.matchAll()` into an Array

If you want to use a regular expression to match (**with** [capture groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Backreferences)) as an array, and chain [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) methods on, all you have to do is [spread (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) [`<string>.matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) into a `[]`:

```js
const mapped = [...'a b c'.matchAll(/(?<letter>[abc])/g)]
console.log(mapped)
// Outputs: (3) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
```

Now I can do whatever on the [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) capture group(s):

```js
const mapped = [...'a b c'.matchAll(/(?<letter>[abc])/g)]
const onlyAorC = mapped.filter(({groups:{letter}}) => ['a','c'].includes(letter))
console.log(onlyAorC)
// Outputs: (2) [Array(2), Array(2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @ajaykools's answer, you can just paste the following into a `RegExpExtensions.ts` file

```
declare global {
  interface RegExp {
    execAll(string: string): RegExpExecArray[];
  }
}

RegExp.prototype.execAll = function (
  this: RegExp,
  string: string,
): RegExpExecArray[] {
  const results: RegExpExecArray[] = [];
  let result: RegExpExecArray | null;
  const regex = new RegExp(this, "g");
  while ((result = regex.exec(string))) {
    results.push(result);
  }
  return results;
};

export {};
```

Then you only need to add `import "[...]/RegExpExtensions"` once atop your `index.ts` and then you should be able to just do the following anywhere in your code:

```
const matches = /pattern/.execAll("some string")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```js
let inputa = `"a" 'b' "c"`
let inputb = `"d" 'e' "f"`
let rx = /["'](.*?)["']/g

function *execAll(expr, input) { 
    while(true) {
        const current = expr.exec(input)
        if (!current) {
            break
        }
        yield current
    }
}

for (const current of execAll(rx, inputa)) {
  console.log(current)
}

console.log(Array.from(execAll(rx, inputb)))
```